# Prove that $ e^x>2\cdot\left(e^x-\sum_{n=0}^{100}\frac{x^n}{n!}\right) $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

$$
e^x>2\cdot (e^x-\frac{x^{100}+100x^{99}+100\cdot99\cdot x^{98}+...+100!\cdot x+100!}{100!})
$$
proof that it's true for every x in [0,100]

I was trying to use maclaurin series of $e^x$ and after few steps got something like $$ 1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...+x^{100}/100!-x^{101}/101!-x^{102}/102!-....>0 $$
I have no idea what to do next:(

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the remainder in Taylor Series... in fact
$$
e^x - \frac{x^{100}+ \cdots + 100!}{100!}= e^x - \sum_{n=0}^{100}\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{e^{\xi}}{101!}x^{101}, \quad \xi \in [0,x]
$$

so you proof reduces to show that

$$
e^x > \frac{ 2 e^{\xi} x^{101}}{101!}.
$$

Comment: Given that we cannot a priory exclude $\xi\approx x$, this needs us to show $2\cdot 100^{101}<101!$, which is doomed to fail

Comment: That is true @HagenvonEitzen.

Comment: Already tried this, and that gave me nothing :/